# Why generate random request id for each webpage call

Tags: url, random

**Login page url:** https://www.xyz.com/BankAwayRetail/(S(e0x2et4504nzrn45z31vqy45))/RetailSignOn.aspx?RequestId=32421307

**Page once logged in:** https://www.xyz.com/BankAwayRetail/(S(e0x2et4504nzrn45z31vqy45))/main.aspx?RequestId=63780285

Check above link for reference

1. Login page URL has server cookie id along with `RequestId` composed of some random 8 digit number
2. Once I login the next page URL has `RequestId` which is different from the previous one

Why do you need to have a randomly generated `RequestId` for each request?

The href for that particular page reads like this:

```
href="tranHttpHandler.aspx?bwayparam=qDoMNTYEhwvj0TpGy2N1HXlySZCfb3%2f9T7WT5Mm1fg%3d%3d"
```

It might be possible that `RequestId` is encoded in var `bwayparam`?

Please explain why you would do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers will cache data based on the given URL.  Having a unique request id ensures the browser will always request and re-load the page data.

For example, since it appears what you are referring to is a bank application, if the site is designed to show up-to-date values in the user's account, a cached web-page may not show the most recent transaction.  Adding a request id will ensure the page gets reloaded, thereby displaying the most recent information.

Comment: Hi cegfault, if i use HTTPS then do i still need to take care of caching? because i am getting mixed answers for caching activity using https

Comment: It really depends on (a) browser and (b) the HTTP-headers.  Some browsers don't cache HTTPS normally, but *will* if the headers say the content is public.  Because this behavior is not 100% consistent across the board, I would still recommend using a request ID if you want to ensure the data gets re-loaded.